# How can I get captions of YouTube videos using R?

Tags: r, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am familiar with the YouTube API and the 'tuber' package for R. However, when I try to use this package, I am not able to get captions for YouTube videos and do not understand why. For example, the following simple code returns an error:

```
get_captions(id="OFcXgFBzMlE")
```

What is the best way to get captions of YouTube videos? I am open to using Tuber as well as other approaches. I am OK with just getting captions of only some videos (e.g., those that have CC enabled) but need to do so en masse for a large number of videos.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I got a 404, even after trying a couple of different video id's

Comment: I also got 404... it seems you may need to provide the caption ID, rather than the video ID. In this vein, I tried the following code and still got a 404 :(  <br> cid = list_caption_tracks(part = "id, snippet", video_id = tid, lang = "en")$items[[1]]$id <br> get_captions(cid)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Captions.download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) id is:

> **id**
>
> The id parameter identifies the caption track that is being >retrieved. The value is a caption track ID as identified by the id
> property in a caption resource.

So it's not a videoId. You use videoId when making a call to [Captions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#try-it).

Answer (score 0):

get_captions() in tuber package does not work for some reasons.
I recommend you using my newly developed R package called "youtubecaption."
Please install the package using the following command in your R console:

```r
install.packages("youtubecaption")
```

Please visit [**this GitHub repo**](https://github.com/jooyoungseo/youtubecaption) for detailed information about how to use this package.